# Github open repository only for several persons

Tags: github, permissions, repository, test-project

I have a task on GitHub for interview with new applicants on some developers positions in a company.

How can I open this task only for several people, so each can send me a pull request but no one could see others results?
If I add them to the repo they will be able to see results.

Thx.